# Why does using `yes` on bash pipelines *not* cause infinite loops?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

According to its documentation, bash waits until all commands in a pipeline have finished running before continuing

> The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

**So why does the command `yes | true` finish immediately?** Shouldn't the `yes` loop forever and cause the pipeline to never return?

---

And a subquestion: according to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02), shell pipelines may choose to either return after the last command finishes or wait until all the commands finish. Do common shells have different behavior in this sense? Are there any shells where `yes | true` will loop forever?

Comment: `yes | tee >(true) >/dev/null` will do as you expect, btw, as `tee` continues until all writers are dead, so `true` exiting won't disrupt it entirely.

Comment: `true` is basically a `{return 0;}` program, so I wouldn't expect it to run for long, let alone forever.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When `true` exits, the read side of the pipe is closed, but `yes` continues trying to write to the write side.  This condition is called a "broken pipe", and it causes the kernel to send a `SIGPIPE` signal to `yes`.  Since `yes` does nothing special about this signal, it will be killed.  If it ignored the signal, its `write` call would fail with error code `EPIPE`.  Programs that do that have to be prepared to notice `EPIPE` and stop writing, or they will go into an infinite loop.

If you do `strace yes | true`<sup>1</sup> you can see the kernel preparing for both possibilities:

```
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 4096) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=17556, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

`strace` is watching events via the debugger API, which first tells it about the system call returning with an error, and then about the signal.  From `yes`'s perspective, though, the signal happens first.  (Technically, the signal is delivered after the kernel returns control to user space, but before any more machine instructions are executed, so the `write` "wrapper" function in the C library does not get a chance to set `errno` and return to the application.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Sadly, `strace` is Linux-specific.  Most modern Unixes have *some* command that does something similar, but it often has a different name, it probably doesn't decode syscall arguments as thoroughly, and sometimes it only works for root.

Comment: How can I see that output you got, btw? And do you think you can build a minimal example that loops forever? :)

Comment: Looks like `strace` output.

Comment: @hugomg The `strace` command produces that output.

Comment: nvm about the second question. `yes 1>&2 | true` seems to do the trick!

Comment: @hugomg in that case, the pipe is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Its totally relevant to the question though. It loops forever :)

Comment: @hugomg because nothing in `yes` is connected to pipe.

Comment: It's true, that is a demonstration of the documented behavior "wait until all commands finish before terminating the pipeline". It just prevents `yes` from getting SIGPIPE, since the FD it's writing to isn't connected to a pipe.

Comment: @hugomg, it's looping forever in the same way that `yes >/dev/null` is looping forever. It demonstrates nothing at all about pipelines that isn't also true of simple commands (as the waiting-for-termination behavior Tom points out is true of simple commands as well).

Comment: This is incorrect: `write()` does not return at all.  Instead, `SIGPIPE` is raised.  You will only get `EPIPE` if you ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal.

Comment: @DietrichEpp `strace` is watching via the debugger interface, so what it sees can differ a little from what the program sees.  Looking at the code, Linux's `pipe_write` queues up *both* a `SIGPIPE` signal and an `EPIPE` error return, and then (on x86, anyway) debugger notification of syscall exit happens before signal delivery. I'm not even sure that qualifies as a bug; notionally signals cannot happen in the middle of a syscall.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "signals cannot happen in the middle of a syscall"... since signals are normally what we use to interrupt syscalls, and a signal delivered during a syscall will be handled first before the syscall returns.  I wouldn't really call it a bug, since we know what's going on in the program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp When a signal is delivered to a program that's either executing instructions in kernel mode, or blocked, that always causes the kernel to back out of the current syscall in some fashion; so from the *kernel's* perspective, the signal is delivered after the syscall returns.  The *program* sees its handler execute before the *syscall wrapper* returns, but if you look at the ucontext in the handler, the stashed PC will be either one instruction after or one before the syscall trap, depending on whether you're in SA_RESTART mode.

Comment: @zwol: I think we are using our terms with slightly different meanings here, or thinking about things from slightly different perspectives… but in either case, `write()` (the function in libc) does not return (transfer control to the PC following it) until after the signal handler has run, but since the signal handler terminates the program, control is never transferred and therefore `write()` never returns.  Yes, that's implemented in the kernel by having some `xxx_write()` function return `-EPIPE`, but we're debugging a user-space program and uninterested in that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think I see what you're trying to say, now, and how the answer gives the wrong impression.  I revised the answer to explain what's going on in more detail, and why `strace` sees something subtly different from what the application sees.  It's stuck in the review queue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any shells where yes | true will loop forever?

Unlikely, since the `yes` command is using the pipe, and it will fail when the pipe is broken. `sleep` on the other hand, doesn't use the pipe, so:

```
sleep 100000000 | true
```

will run for 100000000 seconds, at least.

Comment: Be careful on all modern shells that don't fork for the last (rightmost) builtin command in a pipe and where `true` is a builtin. This applies to recent versions of the `Bourne Shell`, `ksh93`, `zsh`. If you hit `^Z` when such a command is running, this will suspend the sleep and the shell will never be able to recover without external help.

Comment: @schily On zsh I get: `zsh: job can't be suspended`. Interesting.

Comment: Interesting: which version do you have?

Comment: @schily `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`, on Arch Linux.

Comment: zsh 4.3.4 (i386-pc-solaris2.11) here, so it seems this was modified recently. Interesting idea, I'll need to have a look whether I can implement a similar fix for the Bourne Shell. There is still a question how it works, and which tty process group is used as in the Bourne Shell the fact that the righmost command is a builtin is discovered after the process group for the sleep was already set up for ever.

Comment: BTW: ksh93 has sleep as a builtin and if this is run alone, typing `^Z` causes `ksh93` to fork off a new process with the remaining sleep interval that could be continued.

Comment: @schily, which recent versions of Bourne are you talking about? The recently-maintained branch I'm aware of is the Heirloom version, and its semantics are still generally 70s-era.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy from what I understand, schily maintains a version of sh, to which he backports improvements from modern shells. He's posted about it here, somewhere.

Comment: Heh -- http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.php, indeed.

Comment: The Bourne Shell in the heirloom archives was maintained until ~ 2007 but never was made fully portable as it still contains calls to `sbrk()`. A portable and maintained version is in the schily tools bundle and @Charles Duffy already discovered a location for information ;-)

Comment: @muru many of the features I backported to the Bourne Shell are from my `bsh` (Berthold Shell from VBERTOS, a virtual memory enhanced version of UNOS - the first UNIX clone). Bsh did get many csh features in 1984 and 1985 but the alias mechanism from UNOS was superior to the one from csh in 1980 already. Other new Bourne Shell features are from POSIX, to let it approach POSIX compliance.