# Process not closing when stdin is closed

Tags: process, pipe

I am starting a process with a program.  I expect the process to terminate when the program does, since it loses its stdin.

I terminated the program, then went to the proc/pid/fd for the process, and found that its stdin is still linked to /dev/pts/2.

Why won't the process close in this case?  Better yet, is there a wrapper or technique I can use to ensure that the program will close when its stdin pipe closes?

Comment: `1` is stdout, not stdin.

Comment: It shows in `red` for every pipe. Because `ls` tries to do a `lstat` on the result of `readlink`, but that string returned by `readlink` is not a real path on the file system for pipes or any other fd that doesn't point to a file (also include sockets). There's no way to detect a broken via stat()/lstat() on /proc/pid/fd/*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Thanks for pointing out this mistake with the fd number

Comment: Related: [Why does using `yes` on bash pipelines *not* cause infinite loops?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243350/70524)

Comment: Your question is a lot less clear now. How did you _terminate_ the program? What has that to do with closing a stdin pipe?

Comment: If the process's stdin is `/dev/pts/2`, then its stdin is NOT a pipe, it's a terminal window.

Comment: "I am starting a process with a program, I expect the process to terminate when the program does" is very confusing, because *every process* is executing *some* program, and a program cannot be executed without a process to do it. I think what you really mean is you have *two processes* (and two programs); process A has created process B and is feeding it input over a pipe (or it's supposed to, anyway) and you expect B to go away when A does, since there is no more input.  Is that right?

Answer (score 27):

`stdin` is file descriptor `0`. Closing a file descriptor of a process is something that can only be done actively by the process itself. stdin is closed when the process decides to close it period.

Now, when the stdin of a process is the reading end of a pipe, the other end of the pipe can be open by one or more other processes. When all the file descriptors to the other end have been closed, reading from that pipe will read the remaining data still in that pipe, but will then end up returning nothing (instead of waiting for more data) meaning end-of-file.

Applications like `cat`, `cut`, `wc`... that read from their stdin will usually exit when that happens because their role is to process their input till the end until there's no more input.

There's no magic mechanism that causes applications to die when the end of their input is reached, only them deciding to exit when that happens.

In:

```
echo foo | cat
```

Once `echo` has written `"foo\n"`, it exits which causes the writing end of the pipe to be closed, then the `read()` done by `cat` at the other end returns 0 bytes, which tells `cat` there's nothing more to read and then `cat` decides to exit.

In

```
echo foo | sleep 1
```

`sleep` only exits after 1 second has elapsed. Its stdin becoming a closed pipe has no incidence on that, `sleep` is not even reading from its stdin.

It's different on the writing end of pipes (or sockets for that matters).

When all the fds on the reading end have been closed, any attempt to write on the fds open to the writing end causes a SIGPIPE to be sent to the process causing it to die (unless it ignores the signal in which case the `write()` fails with `EPIPE`).

But that only happens when they try to write.

For instance, in:

```
sleep 1 | true
```

Even though `true` exits straight away and the reading end is then closed straight away, `sleep` is not killed because it doesn't attempt to write to its stdout.

---

Now, about `/proc/fd/pid/n` showing in red in the `ls -l --color` output (as mentioned in [the first version of your question](/revisions/265464/1)), that's only because `ls` does a `lstat()` on the result of `readlink()` on that symlink to try and determine the type of the target of the link.

For file descriptors opened on pipes, or sockets or files in other namespaces, or deleted files, the result of `readlink` will not be an actual path on the file system, so the second `lstat()` done by `ls` will fail and `ls` will think it's a broken symlink, and broken symlinks are rendered in red. You'll get that with any fd to any end of any pipe, whether the other end of the pipe is closed or not. Try with `ls --color=always -l /proc/self/fd | cat` for instance.

To determine whether a fd points to a broken pipe, on Linux, you can try `lsof` with the `-E` option.

```
$ exec 3> >(:) 4> >(sleep 999)
$ lsof -ad3-4 -Ep "$$"
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
zsh     13155 stephane    3w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 5322414 pipe
zsh     13155 stephane    4w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 5323312 pipe 392,sleep,0r
```

For the fd 3, lsof was not able to find any other process at the reading end of the pipe. Beware though, that you could get output like:

```
$ exec 5<&3
$ lsof -ad3-5 -Ep "$$"
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
zsh     13155 stephane    3w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 5322414 pipe 13155,zsh,5w
zsh     13155 stephane    4w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 5323312 pipe 392,sleep,0r
zsh     13155 stephane    5w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 5322414 pipe 392,sleep,3w 13155,zsh,3w
```

fds 3 and 5 are still to broken pipes, because there's no fd to the reading end (there seems to be a bug in lsof, since the fact that `sleep` also has its fd 3 open to the broken pipe is not reflected everywhere).

---

To kill a process as soon as the pipe open on its stdin loses its last writer (becomes broken), you could do something like:

```
run_under_watch() {
  perl -MIO::Poll -e '
     if ($pid = fork) {
       $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
         wait;
         exit($? & 127 ? ($? & 127) + 128 : $? >> 8);
       };
       $p = IO::Poll->new; $p->mask(STDIN, POLLERR); $p->poll;
       kill "TERM", $pid;
       sleep 1;
       kill "KILL", $pid;
       exit(1);
     } else {
       exec @ARGV
     }' "$@"
 }
```

Which would watch for an error condition on stdin (and on Linux, that seems to happen as soon as there's no writer left, even if there's data left in the pipe) and kill the child command as soon as it happens. For instance:

```
 sleep 1 | run_under_watch sleep 2
```

Would kill the `sleep 2` process after 1 second.

Now, generally that's a bit of a silly thing to do. That means you're potentially killing a command before it has had time to process the end of its input. For instance, in:

```
 echo test | run_under_watch cat
```

You'll find that `cat` is sometimes killed before it has had time to output (or even to read!) `"test\n"`. There's no way around that, our *watcher* can't know how much time the command needs to process the input. All we can do is give a grace period before the `kill "TERM"` hoping it's enough for the command to read the content left in the pipe and do what it needs to do with it.

Comment: An additional useful example would be `sort`, which can't even *begin* to produce output until after it has read *all* of its input, and it may have to do a great deal of work in between.