# How does a pipeline knows when to stop

Tags: pipe

Some programs can have an infinite runtime and produce infinite output.
When used in a pipe with a command that finish, how does the pipeline knows when to stop ?

For instance, take `yes` (infinite output) with `head`:

```
 yes | head -n 5
```

It will only yield 5 `y`.

Is the first command that end the one that stop the other processes input/output ?
How does it works ?

Comment: Related - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243352/117549

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The commands are connected with a pipe (I'm talking the system primitive here—obviously, they're connected with a `|`). When the read end of the pipe (the `stdin` of `head`) becomes `close`d (== when `head` either explicitly (`close`) or implicitly (exit) closes it), attempts to write to the write end (`stdout` of `yes`) will fail.

By default, this is not just a regular `errno` failure, but a failure that results in the writing process receiving the `SIGPIPE` signal. The default handler action of the [SIGPIPE signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGPIPE) is to terminate.

In short—if you write to a broken pipe, the system will send you a `SIGPIPE` and by default, a `SIGPIPE` will kill you. That is why `yes` terminates when `head` has ended (and thereby broken the pipe).

---

If you ignore `SIGPIPE` in the parent shell, then the commands will inherit this disposition and a `write` to a broken pipe will simply cause an `errno` error of `EPIPE`. As it appears, `yes` stringifies this error an prints it:

```
$ (trap "" SIGPIPE; yes | head -n 5)  
y
y
y
y
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
yes: write error
```

Comment: That was exaclty the answer I was looking for. So a part of a pipe can terminate but the other continue (if `SIGPIPE` is ignored) ? Have you an example in mind ?

Comment: @Cyrbil In the example with the trap, `yes` exits purely voluntarily. Consider a pipeline where the writer is a while loop: `(trap "" SIGPIPE; while : ; do echo a; echo b >&2; sleep 0.2; done | head -n 5)`—it goes happily on except `echo a;` will only succeed 5 times. Similarly, the reader end can close its stdin explicitly (in C by doing `close(0);`, in shell by doing `exec 0>&-`)(probably causing the writer process to die from SIGPIPE) rather than implicitly (=by exitting) and continue .