# `yes | head` why command yes here stops when head is over

Tags: linux, pipe

The command `yes` prints "y" on stdout forever. Head prints the first 10 lines of the input.
Why yes stops when head stops ? I have my little idea but I'm just not sure so I ask here. To me the pipe creates a pipe and replace head stdin by the pipe input. Then when head ends, its program closes the pipe input and somehow the `yes` command notices it and decides it should stop too.

Comment: ... a perhaps closer duplicate [How does a pipeline knows when to stop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268344/how-does-a-pipeline-knows-when-to-stop)

Comment: Thanks, updated!